# Reload a Component

Tags: vuejs2

I have 3 components. They are `dashboard.vue`, `datatable.vue` and `modalbody.vue`. After login my application reach in `dashboard.vue`. Where I call `datatable.vue` to display a list with some `props`. I have a button in `datatable.vue`. If I click on that button a modal will open to add new record to add that list (`datatable.vue`) using `modalbody.vue`.

Now I need to reload that list (`datatable.vue`) after inserting new record through modal (`modalbody.vue`).

How can I do that ?

Comment: Vue is data driven. Generally, a datatable in vue is probably using v-for to output an `array of data`. Therefore, if you want to add a new record to the datatable, you gotta find a way to add it to the  `array of data` first, and the new record will be displayed automatically.

Comment: Thanks @JacobGoh. I'll try. Thanks.

Comment: @JacobGoh. I am using `<tr v-for="obj in gdata">` code for the list. Here  `gdata` is coming from another component as `props`. How can I populate this `gdata` in current component ?

Comment: i think you may use [.sync modifier](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier) or [global event bus](https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/) to update the `gdata` in parent component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am going to show you a simple example how to do it.Hope you will get the logic

*Component which has the table:*

```
<template>
    <div>
        <cmp :modal.sync="modal" @personAdded="addItemInTable"></cmp>
        <button @click="addNewPerson">add person</button>
        <table>
            <tr v-for="row in tableRows">
                <td>{{ row.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ row.lastName }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import childComponent from 'ChildComponent.vue'
    export default {
        components: {
            "cmp": childComponent
        },
        data() {
            return {
                modal: false,
                tableRows: [
                    { name: "person1", lastName: "lperson1" },
                    { name: "person2", lastName: "lperson2" },
                    { name: "person3", lastName: "lperson3" },
                    { name: "person4", lastName: "lperson4" },
                ]
            }
        },
        methods: {
            addNewPerson() {
                this.modal = true //open the modal
            },
            addItemInTable(data) {
                //saving the data passed from modal
                this.tableRows.unshift(data)
                this.modal = false
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

*Modal Component:*

```
<template>
    <div id="modal" v-if="modal">
        <input type="text" v-model="name">
        <input type="text" v-model="">
        <button @click="save">Save</button>
        <button @click="cancel">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            modal: {
                default: false
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                name: '',
                lastName: ''
            }
        },
        methods: {
            save() {
                const savedData = {
                    name: this.name,
                    lastName: this.lastName
                }

                this.$emit('personAdded', savedData)
            },
            cancel() {
                this.$emit('update:modal', false)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<style>
    .modal {
        position: absolute;
        height: 500px;
        width: 500px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        z-index: 999;
    }
</style>
```

> I dont have run the above code but the logic is correct.Please read below to understand:

- For .sync modifier read [this](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/vues-v-model-directive-vs-sync-modifier-d1f83957c57c)
- For emitting events ($emit) read [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event)
- For reusing components read [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Reusing-Components)